# How do I apply some function to a python meshgrid?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Say I want to calculate a value for every point on a grid. I would define some function `func` that takes two values `x` and `y` as parameters and returns a third value. In the example below, calculating this value requires a look-up in an external dictionary. I would then generate a grid of points and evaluate `func` on each of them to get my desired result.

The code below does precisely this, but in a somewhat roundabout way. First I reshape both the X and Y coordinate matrices into one-dimensional arrays, calculate all the values, and then reshape the result back into a matrix. My questions is, can this be done in a more elegant manner?

```
import collections as c

# some arbitrary lookup table
a = c.defaultdict(int)
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 2
a[4] = 3

def func(x,y):
    # some arbitrary function
    return a[x] + a[y]

X,Y = np.mgrid[1:3, 1:4]
X = X.T
Y = Y.T

Z = np.array([func(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(X.ravel(), Y.ravel())]).reshape(X.shape)
print Z
```

The purpose of this code is to generate a set of values that I can use with `pcolor` in matplotlib to create a heatmap-type plot.

Comment: codereview.stackoverflow.com is probably a better place for this

Comment: I believe that `X.reshape(X.size)` is the same as `X.ravel()`

Comment: You might also want to look into [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd use `numpy.vectorize` to "vectorize" your function.  Note that despite the name, `vectorize` is not intended to make your code run faster -- Just simplify it a bit.

Here's some examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> @np.vectorize
... def foo(a, b):
...    return a + b
... 
>>> foo([1,3,5], [2,4,6])
array([ 3,  7, 11])
>>> foo(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 6,  8, 10],
       [12, 14, 16]])
```

With your code, it should be enough to decorate `func` with `np.vectorize` and then you can probably just call it as `func(X, Y)` -- No `ravel`ing or `reshape`ing necessary:

```
import numpy as np
import collections as c

# some arbitrary lookup table
a = c.defaultdict(int)
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[3] = 2
a[4] = 3

@np.vectorize
def func(x,y):
    # some arbitrary function
    return a[x] + a[y]

X,Y = np.mgrid[1:3, 1:4]
X = X.T
Y = Y.T

Z = func(X, Y)
```

Comment: We can also apply `vectorize` as a function directly. For example, vectorising the built-in `chr(..)` function: `np.vectorize(chr)(np.arange(97, 107))` gives `array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 
      dtype='|S1')`.

Comment: That's true -- But you're just unraveling the decorator syntactic sugar.  The downside is that you'll be creating a new function each time that line is executed which is a somewhat expensive operation.  With the decorator syntax, _usually_ the line is only executed once (at import time) so it's not as big of a concern.