# Find max average of column C while minimizing filter of column A and filter of column B

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sorting, filter

How do I find the max average of remaining column C values after filtering column A where A > x where x is minimized and filtering column B where B > y where y is minimized?

This is not the correct way to write this, but here goes:

Min(x)A, Min(y)B = Max(average(C))

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
        0  1  2
0                     0.955264              0.018151                1.069599
1                     0.250984              0.021228                0.565075
2                     0.214348              0.010068                0.553522
3                     0.209648              0.005857                5.299407
4                     0.201268              0.019254               -2.655558
5                     0.180277              0.008406               -2.243170
6                     0.121976              0.012358                0.741234
7                     0.113862              0.002437               -0.459225
8                     0.094065              0.007480               -2.203349
9                     0.073183              0.002110                0.401326
10                    0.069058              0.000474               -0.565729
11                    0.059394              0.001699               -2.841782
12                    0.053492              0.000076                0.572350
13                    0.051462              0.011117               -4.751399
14                    0.044621              0.001428                1.726456
15                    0.038060              0.002472                2.900067
16                    0.035086              0.000642                2.847032
17                    0.027002              0.012311               -3.224638
18                    0.023652              0.003301               -0.401571
19                    0.017891              0.013588               -2.357813
20                    0.010771              0.003337                1.775200
21                    0.005131              0.003372                1.644813
```

REAL DATA:
rows: 135,269
combinations: 18,297,702,361

The best way to describe this is with this unusably slow code below:

```
def process_all(df):
column_names = ['pcp1', 'pcpr1', 'alc', 'clc']
maxvalues_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
max_leading_change = 0

for i1, r1 in df.iterrows():
    print(i1)
    cp1 = df.iloc[i1].predicted_change_percent_1
    filter_cp = df.loc[(df['pcp1'] >= cp1)]

    for i2, r2 in filter_cp.iterrows():

        cpr1 = filter_cp.iloc[i2].predicted_cpreturn_1

        filter_cpr = filter_cp.loc[(filter_cp['pcp1'] >= cpr1)]

        average_leading_change = filter_cpr['lcp'].mean()
        
        if average_leading_change > max_leading_change:

            count_leading_change = filter_cpr['lcp'].count()
            max_leading_change = average_leading_change
            max_row = {'pcp1': cp1, 'pcpr1': cpr1, 'alc': average_leading_change, 'clc': count_leading_change}
            maxvalues_df = maxvalues_df.append(max_row, ignore_index=True)
            
maxvalues_df = maxvalues_df.sort_values('alc')
return maxvalues_df
```

**EDIT:**

Below is the same function but using NumPy arras and sorting. I thought it would be 1000x faster, but alas, it was only 10x faster.

```
def process_all(df):
max_leading_change = 0
final_list = []
nump_df=df.values
#print(nump_df)

sortedArr1 = nump_df[nump_df[:,0].argsort()[::-1]]

for i1 in range(1, sortedArr1.shape[0] + 1):
    print(i1)
    filteredArr1 = sortedArr1[:i1]

    sortedArr2 = filteredArr1[filteredArr1[:,1].argsort()[::-1]]
    cp1 = filteredArr1[i1-1][0]
    
    
    for i2 in range(1, sortedArr2.shape[0] + 1):
        
        filteredArr2 = sortedArr2[:i2]
        average_leading_change = filteredArr2[:,2].mean()
                
        if average_leading_change > max_leading_change:
            cpr2 = filteredArr2[i2-1][1]
          
            # date = filteredArr2[i1-1][4]
            print(f'cp1: {cp1} | cpr2: {cpr2} | average_leading_change: {average_leading_change} | count: {i2}')
            # print(filteredArr2)
            max_leading_change = average_leading_change
            max_row = [cp1, cpr2, average_leading_change, i2]
            final_list.append(max_row) 

final_array = np.array(final_list)
# print(final_array)
return final_array
```

**EDIT 2:**

I feel there might be a linear programming solution here, but I'm not familiar with linear programming.

**EDIT 3:**

This third iteration is really fast it can try 10,000 combinations in 3 seconds. But at that rate, it will take over 2,000 hours to go through 18,297,702,361 combinations.

```
def average(nump_df, x, y):
mask = (nump_df[:, 0] >= x) & (nump_df[:, 1] >= y)
filterArr = nump_df[mask]
if filterArr.size == 0:
    return None, None

return filterArr[:,2].mean(), filterArr.shape[0]

def process_all(df):
df.dropna(inplace=True)
nump_df = df.values
nump_df = nump_df[nump_df[:,0].argsort()[::-1]]
max_avg = 0
final_list = []
i = 0
# rows: 135,269
# combinations: 18,297,702,361
for x,y in itertools.product(nump_df[:,0],nump_df[:,1]):
    avg, count = average(nump_df, x, y)
    if avg is None:
        continue

    if avg > max_avg:
        max_avg = avg
        max_row = [x, y, avg, count]
        final_list.append(max_row)
    if (i % 10000) == 0:
        print(i)
    i = i + 1 

final_array = np.array(final_list)
return final_array
```

**EDIT 4:**

This does not work. It requires 136 GB of memory on the entire dataset. And it's not returning correct Z values on a small dataset. It's fast though.

```
class Optimizer(object):
nump_df: np.array

def __init__(self):
    self.nump_df = None

@np.vectorize
def average(self, x, y):
    mask = (self.nump_df[:, 0] >= x) & (self.nump_df[:, 1] >= y)
    filterArr = self.nump_df[mask]
    if filterArr.size == 0:
        return None

    return filterArr[:,2].mean() #, filterArr.shape[0]

def process_all(self, df):
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    self.nump_df = df.values
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(self.nump_df[:,0], self.nump_df[:,1], sparse=True, indexing='xy')
    X = xx.T
    Y = yy.T
    Z = self.average(self,X,Y)
    print(Z)
```

**EDIT 5:**

What does the entire dataset look like?
[Distribution of X, Y, Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGYHd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a faster version. It uses more memory though because it tabulates everything in 2 large numpy arrays (shape `[n_unique_x_values, n_unique_y_values]`). This is not feasible for your case of 128k lines if there are about 128k unique values for x and y each present. But you might be able to improve it further. For instance the time for looking up the indices `i_x` & `i_y` for each line could be reduced from `O(N)` to `O(log N)` or even `O(1)` by using a dict. The 2 arrays `sums` & `counts` could be replaced by some sparse data structure although I'm not sure how that could work (some nested interval data structure?) ...

```
xs = sorted(set(nump_df[:,0]))
ys = sorted(set(nump_df[:,1]))

sums = np.zeros([len(xs), len(ys)])
counts = np.zeros([len(xs), len(ys)])  
for x, y, z in nump_df:
    i_x = xs.index(x)
    i_y = ys.index(y)
    sums[:i_x+1, :i_y+1] += z
    counts[:i_x+1, :i_y+1] += 1

mask = (counts > 0)
avgs = np.zeros(sums.shape) 
avgs[mask] = sums[mask] / counts[mask]
idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(avgs[mask]), sums.shape)
print(xs[idx[0]], ys[idx[1]], avgs[idx], counts[idx])
```

Interestingly my implementation prompts a "better" solution for your sample input, because there are multiple combinations of x and y prompting the same average for z and in my implementation the one with minimal y happens to be found first (probably because it's the upperleft-most solution) while in your implementation another combination of x and y is returned.

Comment: You are correct. I can't get this to run on the real dataset. 

sums = np.zeros([len(xs), len(ys)])
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 136. GiB for an array with shape (135091, 135022) and data type float64

Comment: There must be a way to apply, lambda, or vectorize a function so that no for loops are required similar to this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20228722/4476840

Comment: How are x and y distributed in your full dataset? If there's no strong correlation between them, you could try to segment the dataset into rectangles. Assume that you can partition the xy matrix into 4x4 rectangles, each containing about 1/16 of rows. For a row x' y' z' in one of the rectangles: instead of adding z' to every single element x <= x', y <= y' you could instead add z' to a single scalar for each rectangle. The maximum average operation could be done locally in each rect & use the scalar as an offset for global maximum comparison. This would allow to parallelize/serialize the algo

Comment: They are not well correlated. This is an interesting idea. I had an idea for an average competition. But I don't know how I would make it work. I'll add the image of the distribution as a comment.