# Vectorize a function in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

def foo(args):
    [a, x, y, z, b1] = args
    vals = np.random.uniform(0, 10, a)
    rr= np.random.uniform(1, 2, a)
    u_1 = vals - x
    u_2 = vals * rr - y
    u_3 = vals / rr - z
    Q = sum(sum(u_1[None, :] > np.maximum(u_2[None, :], u_3[None, :])))
    # print(Q)
    if Q > b1:
        Q = 10
    return Q

args = [10, 2, 40, 1, 2]
print(foo(args))  # this works fine
x_ = [*range(5, 13, 1)]
y_ = [*range(2, 50, 5)]
z_ = [*range(4, 8, 1)]
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing="ij")
args = [10, x, y, z, 2]
print(foo(args))  # this does not work
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (8,10,4)

I want to evaluate the function `foo(args)` at all the points of the meshgrid. How should I modify `foo(args)`?
I need a vectorization implementation of this operation as it needs to be very fast.

I already know the following answer: [How do I apply some function to a python meshgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228546/how-do-i-apply-some-function-to-a-python-meshgrid). I just think there might be a way to speed up the evaluation of the function.

Comment: `np.vectorize` exists but from the docs: The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: You could try: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html for more efficient vectorization but I am not expert in this

Comment: Full error traceback please.  Without that we are left guessing where the error occurs.

Comment: I ran your code and found that the error occurs in the `vals-x` line of your function.  `vals` clearly is (10,) shape.  `x`  comes from `meshgrid`, and by the error is (8,10,4). Do you know what is meant by `broadcasting`?  You must have some idea since you used `None` in the `Q` calculation.

Comment: Why did you give up so easily on the `broadcasting` error.  The `np.vectorize` is a lazy-mans way of applying broadcasting - to a function that only takes scalar inputs.  That doesn't describe your `foo` function, does it?  Make sure you understand your errors, before randomly trying alternative "fixes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Use the `np.expand_dims()` like this.

```
    x, y, z = [np.expand_dims(e, axis=-1) for e in (x, y, z)]
    u_1 = vals - x
    u_2 = vals * rr - y
    u_3 = vals / rr - z
    Q = np.sum(u_1 > np.maximum(u_2, u_3), axis=-1)
    Q = np.where(Q > b1, 10, Q)
```

And I refactored unnecessary indexing like `u_1[None, :]` and `sum()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.vectorize` to vectorize your `foo` function. And use `exlucded` option to exclude the arguments for being vectorized. In your case, arguments `a` and `b1` doesn't need to be vectorized. So, you need to modify your `foo` first:

```
def foo(a, x, y, z, b1):
    # [a, x, y, z, b1] = args -> comment this line
```

Passing the list to the function using `foo(*args)` instead of `foo(args)`. Then vectorize the `foo` function:

```
vec_func = np.vectorize(foo, excluded=['a', 'b1'])
args = [10, x, y, z, 2]
print(foo(*args))  # it works now
```

Comment: FYI, the OP meant "vectorizing" as a technique for a performance benefit, like in "Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python", which is from [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). And as Caridorc
  said in a comment on the question, the ```np.vectorize()``` performs bad.